# Error when adding Role to my user in a scratch org

Tags: scratch-org, user-record, roles

I came across this issue when trying to add a role to my own user, in order to have the account serve as a community account for community user provisioning. I also tried creating another admin with the role set from the get-go but same issue. Anybody else seen this?

[image]

Comment: Created a custom Role and all fixed, go figure

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a pretty common issue with scratch orgs, particularly if your org is generated with `hasSampleData: false`. It comes up any time you assign one of the built-in Roles to any User and it's always a gack.

I typically begin scratch org builds that use `hasSampleData: false` with a little Anonymous Apex:

```
delete [SELECT Id FROM UserRole];
UserRole ur = new UserRole(Name = 'CEO');
insert ur;
update new User(Id = UserInfo.getUserId(), UserRoleId = ur.Id);
```

Comment: It appears this error message has changed but the resolution is the same. I'm getting:

"The data you were trying to access could not be found"